# Sharing 3G+ on Windows XP (Hotspot WiFi Server) with mobile

Tags: windows-xp, iphone, 3g, tethering, wireless-networking

I have added WiFi non-encrypted WEP and shared my 3G internet connection through a wireless network ad-hoc.

I **can** see the SSID on my iPhone but I cannot browse the Internet. It says "no connection".

So is this impossible on WinXP? On Windows 7 I could using *connectify* on Windows 7. (Unfortunately connectify doesn't work on XP.)

If not is there any alternative to connectify compatible with XP?

Comment: So your iPhone can't see the ad hoc Wifi network you set up in XP, at all?

Comment: Finally I CAN see the ssid on my iphone but I cannot browse Internet it says no connection.